# Home button takes me to the Default Android Home on HTC Desire X

Tags: htc, htc-sense, home-button, htc-desire-x

The home button on my HTC Desire X used to take me to the HTC sense home. But once I stopped HTC sense from settings-apps & from then on, it takes me to the default android Home (the one with the snow capped mountain etc). Even after I restarted HTC Sense, Re-started the phone & even Factory reset the phone, this behaviour still persists. How do I get back my original home button functionality.

Comment: Are you rooted or able to root? Enable USB debugging, download ADB and try running `adb shell am start com.htc.launcher`. If that doesn't work, pastebin the output of `adb shell pm list packages -s` here.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing a new launcher app (it really doesn't matter if you want it or not, you'll only need it for a few seconds) from the Play Store. Once it's installed, press the home button and Android should prompt you to choose a home app. Choose the one you want, select "Always", and then you can uninstall the launcher app you just installed.

Comment: Didn't work. Even after installing the launcher, home button takes me to the default android home without any prompts.